# How to pass a Bearer API Key in Retrofit2?

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit2, interceptor, bearer-token

Two possibilities : either i pass a header with "Authorization: APIKEY" but it says that i don't have access (code 401) or i pass "Authorization: Bearer APIKEY" and it throws an exception. After looking up on SO i found the solution to add interceptor, also to add a header with "Connection: close" but still, i don't receive the data.

Here's my code :

````
public class RetrofitYouSign {

    private static Retrofit sRetrofit;
    private static final String URL = "https://staging-api.yousign.com/";

    private static OkHttpClient sOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MY-API-KEY")
                                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .addHeader("Connection", "close")
                                    .build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    }).build();

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        if (sRetrofit == null) {
            sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(sOkHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return sRetrofit;
    }

    public interface GetYouSign {

        @GET("users/")
        Call<Yousign> getYouSignData();
    }

}```

And here is my stack if i enter with the name Bearer :

2019-04-11 19:25:12.894 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup I/System.out: [okhttp3.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:69), okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189), okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121), okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121), okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121), com.jmjsolution.solarpro.services.retrofitClient.RetrofitYouSign$1.intercept(RetrofitYouSign.java:31), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147), okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121), okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200), okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147), okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)]
2019-04-11 19:25:12.894 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ��
2019-04-11 19:25:12.894 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:69)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.894 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.894 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.895 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.896 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.896 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.897 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.897 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.897 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at com.jmjsolution.solarpro.services.retrofitClient.RetrofitYouSign$1.intercept(RetrofitYouSign.java:31)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-04-11 19:25:12.898 1492-1492/com.jmjsolution.solarup W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Otherwise i receiver a code 401, if i don't put the word Bearer.

I tried the code with the interceptor (as you can see in my code) but nothing seems to work. Any solution would be really appreciated, thank you.
````

Comment: you have to save it in preference and get it over here in your retrofit adapter and pass it.

Comment: What do you mean save it in preference ? Preference Manager ? Why i have it and i passed it i just didn't write it for privacy purpose !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this int APiInterface class:-

```
@GET("users")
Call<Yousign> getYouSignData(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

or in your activity like this :-

```
getYouSignData("Bearer your api key")
```

Comment: remove / from @GET("users")

Comment: I'm so stupid on it for hours ! Thank you very much ! Was just about the users/ vs users !

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass you (bearer + auth token) as **Authorization** parameter like below:

```
@GET("api/GetProfile)
Call<UserProfile> getProfile(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

then call like this

```
 Call<UserProfile> calltargetResponce = client.getProfile("Bearer "+token);
```